# Unable to run the unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    echo -n "enter the 1 to convert lower to upper or 2 convert upper to lower"
    read n
    echo -in_str "Enter the string here"
    read in_str
    echo $n
    echo $in_str
    if [ $n -eq 1 ] then
        $ echo $in_str| awk '{print toupper($0)}'
    elif [ -n -eq 2 ] then
        $ echo $in_str| awk '{print tolower($0)}'
    else
        echo "please select the correct choice"
    fi
```

Getting error: else unexpected i am unable to run the above code

Comment: Alternatives for awk are `typeset -u in_str` and `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if [ $n -eq 1 ] then
```

Needs to be this:

```
if [ $n -eq 1 ]; then
```

Or this:

```
if [ $n -eq 1 ]
then
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys am very new to unix shell scripting

Comment: assuming `$n` is not blank (or null but normaly not after the read). If not it could be `${n:-9}` to assign (if blank/null) to 9 so `-eq` could be used

Answer (score 1):

You need semicolon(s) before `then`.And you have extra `$` symbols. I think you wanted something like this

```
if [ $n -eq 1 ]; then
    echo $in_str| awk '{print toupper($0)}'
elif [ $n -eq 2 ]; then
    echo $in_str| awk '{print tolower($0)}'
else
    echo "please select the correct choice"
fi
```

At least it seems to work here.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty certain you need `then` on the `elif` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo $in_str| awk '{print toupper($0)}'
```

???

I don't think you want that `$` character at the front of that line (or the other `echo` line either).

In addition, if you want `then` on the same line as your `if`, it should be:

```
if [ $n -eq 1 ] ; then
```